# Array of Strings - Add quotation marks either side of each comma

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, string

I am sending a JSON as a string and because of this even when i parse in an array,
it is sending through without quotation marks, so I am having to add it in manually, shown below.. But doing this means the quotes are only at the start and end making the array have just the one item.

First I concat the names into an array of strings.

```
 var items = [];               
                    order_res.items.forEach(element => {
                        if (order_res.items.length > 1) {
                            items = items.concat(element.name)
```

Then I send it as part of a response, and manually add in the brackets and quotation marks as otherwise they dont appear in the string format the other end so I can then parse it.

```
             `{
                    "message": "Please press 1 or 2 to choose the item from your order",                          
                    "itemNames" : ["${items}"]                 
                }`
```

It comes through the other end like this:

```
  "itemNames" : ["Fashion Summer Floral Print Dress - Black / L,2017 Summer Women Dress Sexy - Black / L"]                 
                }
```

I want quote marks either side of the comma's!

If i just do this:

```
"itemNames" : ${items}
```

It comes through the other end like this:

```
"itemNames" : Fashion Summer Floral Print Dress - Black / L,2017 Summer Women Dress Sexy - Black / L                
                    }
```

And I cant parse it, I am trying to parse it.

Comment: `"itemNames" : ["${items}"` That shouldn't work, don't you need a template literal instead?

Comment: Is it possible to push the strings to the array in the forEach loop?

Comment: @CertainPerformance Oh, well it does, I haven't yet heard of a template literal.

Comment: @Lesleyvdp the 'items' is an array of strings, the problem is if i just parse it in as part of the string of json in the second section, on the other end it doesnt come through as a string of array format.